# Kali Linux won't boot from GUI

Tags: linux, debian, kali-linux

Been working with Kali Linux for over a month. Updated some wheezy & Deb source list. Everything was working fine even with the unsupported sources! But when I tried to install NVIDIA ATI drivers, it works fine with no errors, and as well as after the installation i tested it from `Application -> System Tools -> Preferences -> ATI Catalyst`

My PC hasn't been restarted in over 2 weeks and of course through all this time I am doing other stuff so I may not be sure of what has cause the problem if it is the NVIDIA as I believe or what!

All  get now when reboot is the ttyl window! (Terminal)

Any ideas? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try typing `STARTX` See what happens I'll assume you've not try that since you did not mention anything you've tried to solve the problem. So in case the `STARTX` didn't solve your issue

From the same ttyl1

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade -y
apt-get install -f gdm3
```

I recommend you check this out. [GDM3](https://packages.debian.org/squeeze/gdm3)